# getting error while calling function / c++ and opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have written a function(High) which has a Mat as an output. I am going to use this returned Mat in another function(Filter) to use it as an input for MedianBlur(). This is what I mean:

```
High(); 
Filter();   

Mat Data::High(float* distances){
        Mat Matdis;
...
    return Matdis;
} 


 void Data::Filter(){
    High();
    MedianBlur(Matdis,Matdis,ksize);
 }
```

I get error in MedianBlur line...does anyone know what is the reason?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Matdis undeclared identifier!

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the error message that you forgot to post tells you that `Matdis` wasn't declared in the scope of `Filter`. If you want to pass the return value of `High` as the input of `MedianBlur`, then you'll need to get the return value:

```
Mat high = High(distances);    // You'll need an argument for this function
MedianBlur(high, high, ksize);
```

Comment: Also `High` has a float argument that i think should be added.

Comment: @aa: Then you've got some other error somewhere else. You'll need to use your debugger to find that.